# Refreshing a new document so default displays in computed control

Tags: refresh, xpages, default

This problem has been bugging me for awhile and I can not seem to get around it. So I stripped it down to the most basic level.
1.  created a new XPage and bound it to an exiting form
2.  created a panel called 'displayPanel'
3.  inside the panel create a comboBox and give it a few values and a default value of any valid value.
4.  Set an onChange event that does a partial refresh of displayPanel
5.  Add a computed field that simply displays the value of the comboBox.
6 added a button that does a partial refresh of displayPanel onClick.

Open the XPage and the computed field is blank, make a change and the computed field displays.

open the XPage again and click the refresh button and the computed field displays

Now this is a very simple example but what I need to do is actually more complex but the value of the comboBox (Does not need to be a comboBox) is not available until a refresh is performed. This is only an issue on a new document when it first gets it's defaults.

I have added this:

```
view.postScript("XSP.partialRefreshGet('#{id:displayPanel}')")
```

to every one of the page events but it does not appear to do an actual page refresh like clicking the button or making a change.

I'm at a loss as to how to make this work. If I could get this simple example to work the rest of what I need is easy.

Thanks

Comment: How do you get the value of the combo box in the computed field?

Comment: document1.getValue("myComboBox")

Comment: Try setting the default value combobox in the beforepageload event.
datasource.replaceItemValue("fieldnamne","Value"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fredrik is on the right track -- you should set the value manually during an event -- but I would add two caveats:

- Call `setValue` instead of `replaceItemValue` (e.g. `document1.setValue("myComboBox", "Default Value");`). The comparative advantages might not be applicable in this specific case, but you should be in the habit of always calling `setValue` instead of `replaceItemValue` (and `getValue` instead of `getItemValue`) so that, when you've encountered a scenario where it makes a real difference, you just get that benefit for free... the rest of the time, the methods are equivalent, so you might as well just use the one that requires less typing. :)
- You'll probably need to do this in `afterPageLoad`: the data source may not be ready yet during `beforePageLoad`; depending on why you're referencing the default value elsewhere in your page, `beforeRenderResponse` might be too late; and `afterRenderResponse` would definitely be too late...

...which leads me to ***why*** the `defaultValue` attribute does not behave the way we might expect it to, especially for those of us with experience developing Notes client apps.

The XPages engine splits the processing of every HTTP request into several "phases". Depending on the type of request (initial page load, partial refresh event, etc.) and other factors, the lifecycle will consist of as many as 6 phases and as few as 2.

[This tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html) provides an excellent description of these phases, but in the context of this question, the following are specifically of interest:

- **Apply Request Values**

  When an event runs against a page that has already been loaded (e.g. a user clicks a button, or selects a value from a combobox that has an `onChange` event, etc.), the HTTP request sent to the server to trigger the event includes POST data that represents the value of all editable components. This phase temporarily stores these values in the `submittedValue` property of any affected components, but the data source doesn't "know" what the new values are yet.
- **Process Validations**

  This phase runs any applicable validators and, if any fail, skips straight to the last phase (which means it never runs the code of the event that was triggered).
- **Update Model Values**

  If no validations fail (or none are defined), this phase takes the submitted values and actually stores them in the corresponding data source. Until this point, the data source is completely unaware that there has been any user interaction. This is intended to avoid prematurely polluting any back end data with user input that might not even be valid. Remember, not every data source is a "document"; it might be relational data that is changed via an `UPDATE` the instant `setValue` is called... which is basically what this phase does: it takes the `submittedValue` and calls `setValue` on the corresponding data source (and then sets `submittedValue` to `null`). This separation allows components to simply be visual representations of the state of the back end data -- visual representations that the *user* interacts with; our code should always be interacting directly with the back end data via the abstraction layer of a data source.
- **Render Response**

  Once all of the other phases have run (or been skipped), this phase sends a response to the consumer. In other words, it sends HTML (or JSON, or XML, or PDF, etc.) back to the browser. But the most salient point in the context of this question is that the prior phases are *always* skipped on initial page load. When the user first accesses a page, they haven't had a chance to enter any data yet, so there are no request values to be applied. Since no data has been posted, there's nothing to validate. And -- most pertinent of all -- there's nothing to be pushed to the data model. So a representation of the component tree (or a subset of it, in the case of a partial refresh event) always needs to be sent to the user, but until the user *interacts* with that representation, the data source remains in whatever state it was when the most recent response was rendered... which is why, if you want a specific property of the data source to have a specific value *before* the user interacts with it, your code needs to set that property's value manually.

In summary, components are **visual**. Data sources are **abstract**. Perhaps this behavior would be more self-explanatory if the component property had simply been called `defaultClientValue` instead of `defaultValue`, because that's essentially what it is: a default suggestion to the *user* for what data to *send back* to the data source. But until they do, the data source has not received that value. So if, on initial page load, you need a data source property to have a value that it wouldn't already have in its default state, you should manually call `setValue` to give it the desired value.

**P.S.** Ironically, if you'd called `partialRefreshPost` instead of `partialRefreshGet`, you likely would have achieved the result you were looking for, because the former sends all the form data, while the latter just asks the existing component state to be rendered again. But then you're forcing *all* of the form data to be sent just to update one data source property, so it's better to simply do what's described above.

Comment: Thanks Tim - I will have to work this through. In an earlier iteration of this I had been setting a bunch of fields in the beforePageLoad and it did basically the same thing. I will try it as well as the partialRefreshPost. Setting the values in the before / afterPageLoad seems almost counter intuitive.

Comment: Setting the value of the control in the beforePageLoad seems to work. Did document1.setValue("ACDraftEditors","Bill") and all is well. But, that is a very akward way to get default values into fields and isolates the action a long way away from the control. ie if you look at the control in the designer you would never know that it accepts a default, or you change the control to say accept a number rather than an string and now you default is wrong and not obvious. I did the partialRefreshPost in every page event in my simple test XPage  and that does no good.

Comment: My problem is that I am thinking Notes/Domino and XPages treats the default value way differently. I can not even guess at the hours I've spent trying to make this work. Will go to the beforePageLoad and populate the required defaults. Fortunately, most of them work OK the way it works, but those that are used for other purposes are a pain. Your explaination of it being just a Client Suggestion makes sense, however, I have a couple suggestions for the XPages Designers!